# Copying value of cell (X,Y) to cell (A,B) in same sheet of an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I am using the modules `xlwd`, `xlwt` and `xlutil` to do some Excel manipulations in Python. I am not able to figure out how to copy the value of cell `(X,Y)` to cell `(A,B)` in the same sheet of an Excel file in Python. Could someone let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import xlutils
from xlutils.copy import copy 

r_book = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
w_book = xlutils.copy.copy(r_book)
r_sheet = r_book.sheets()[0] # Taking the first sheet
w_sheet = w_book.get_sheet(0)

x_y_value = r_sheet.cell(X, Y).value
w_sheet.write(A, B, x_y_value)
w_book.save(fname)
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the help. some more changes were needed for the above code to work:  1. from xlutils.copy import copy  2. w_sheet = w_book.get_sheet(0)

Comment: Hi, am facing two issues. First, when I run the code on an "xlsx" file, am not able to open the modified xlsx file. Second, when I operate on "xls" file, the above code works but only text is copied but background color of the cell is not copied. how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Work on 2 cells among tens of thousands...quite meager.
Normally,one should present an iteration over rows x columns.

Comment: Please expand your answer. This doesn't make a lot of sense right now.